# CakePHP 3: Executing console command gives 'Unknown Command `cake hello`' error

Tags: php, cakephp, command, cakephp-3.0

I have been developing locally on a simple cake project creating a console command following the [Console Commands](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/commands.html) documentation. When moving all of the work to the development server running a separate copy of CakePHP (server running version CakePHP 3.5.13 local version running CakePHP 3.6), trying to run the `bin/cake hello` command gives the following error:

```
Exception: Unknown command 'cake hello'. Run 'cake --help' to get the list of valid commands. in [/var/www/vhosts/[SERVER_NAME]/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php, line 177]
```

I have tried creating a new console command from scratch directly on the server but end up with same error which should rule out the command code being the issue.

All files are in the correct place: `src/Command/HelloCommand.php`

The HelloCommand.php code is exactly the same as the example in the documentation.

I am at a miss as to why it cannot find the command. It also doesn't appear in the list of commands when running `cake --help`.

Is there something I have missed to give CakePHP sight to the newly created console commands? Is there any reason why the command runs fine locally but differently on a remote server or have I just missed something!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands are only available as of CakePHP 3.6, in earlier versions you have to use Shells.

Side note: do not use different CakePHP versions, your development and prodution environments should be as identical as possible if you don't want to get in trouble!

See also

- **[Cookbook > 3.x Migration Guide > 3.6 Migration Guide > Console](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-6-migration-guide.html#console)**
- **[Cookbook > Console Tools, Shells & Tasks > Shells](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/shells.html)**

Comment: Thanks, I was in the middle of downgrading my local app to the correct version when I saw the answer. Always knew my first stack question would be a rookie error haha!